# Table alignment according to div size

Tags: css, html

I have table inside div , thing is if I change window size, table is coming out of div. please help me. Thanks in advance. Below is my code

```
<div style="height:auto">
 <table  width="100%" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
  <tr >
    <th  width="16.5%">sunday</th>
    <th width="16.5%">monday</th>
    <th width="16.5%">tuesday</th>
    <th width="16.5%">wed</th>
    <th width="16.5%">thu</th>
    <th width="16.5%">fri</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr  >
    <td>111</td>
    <td ><input value="" type="" name="" /></td>
    <td ><input value="" type="" name="" /></td>
    <td ><input value="" type="" name="" /></td>
    <td ><input value="" type="" name="" /></td>
    <td ><input value="" type="" name="" /></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following `css` in you code

```
div{
    width: 500px; /* you can apply any width to this div */
}

table{
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
table td{
    padding: 5px;
}

input{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/jHwd4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the div to contain the table,you  can use `overflow: auto`. This makes the div scrollable.

But if you don't want it to be scrollable, use `display: table` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in CSS:

```
td input {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the text field size as a percentage
remove table header fixed width.

CSS

```
input{width:100%;}
```

HTML

```
<div style="background-color:#ccc;padding:5px">
 <table >
<thead>
  <tr >
    <th >sunday</th>
    <th >monday</th>
    <th >tuesday</th>
    <th >wed</th>
    <th >thu</th>
    <th>fri</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>111</td>
    <td ><input value="" type="text" name="" /></td>
    <td ><input value="" type="text" name="" /></td>
    <td ><input value="" type="text" name="" /></td>
    <td ><input value="" type="text" name="" /></td>
    <td ><input value="" type="text" name="" /></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G5y3T/1/

Comment: Thank you Nayana Adassuriya

Answer (score 1):

You should set your div style to `display:inline-block;`

[Here you can see a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/YSpG7/)

You should also use an extern css file rather then inline style. **Much** efficienter when you change something.